# Presenting 2 results for one variable using a left brace

Tags: math-mode

So I want to represent two results for a variable in math mode, and there is something that I don't know the name in English for, which is a big "{". What I want to do is the following:

```
\begin{equation}
 \pi(s) = {^{x if s = 5}_{y if s = 4}  
\end{equation}
```

But with a normal size and I don't think this is the correct way. So this line would occupy +- 2 lines instead of 1.

Comment: `{` is a *left brace*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\pi(s)=\begin{cases}
x & \text{if $s = 5$}\\
y & \text{if $s = 4$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the \\[ and \\] for?

Comment: @MiguelSaraiva `\[` and `\]`? They are for unnumbered math mode, aren't they? What do you mean?

Comment: Right, i'm used to using $$ or begin equation I forgot that was a thing. Thank you

Comment: @MiguelSaraiva Well, using `equation` is very okay, but please do not use `$$`!

Comment: oh, I've been using $....$ inline and equation for display, is that ok?

Comment: @MiguelSaraiva Ah, it is okay. Very okay :)